# Expandable search leaving input line bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a expandable search with jQuery and css. When I expand the search and then close it, it leaves a light input line and goes away when I scroll the page.

Not sure what's going on. I'm using [materializecss.com](http://materializecss.com)

jsfidle: https://jsfiddle.net/Shank09/nv6vxeqa/4/

Here is when I expand:
[image]

Here is when I close after expanding:
[image]

Here is after scrolling:
[image]

```js
$(".searchicon").click(function(){
     if($(".searchbox").hasClass("open")){
       $(".searchbox").removeClass("open");
      }
      else{
       $(".searchbox").addClass("open");
        $(".searchbox").focus();
      }
    });
```

```css
    .searchbox {
      width: 0% !important;
    }
    .searchbox.open {
      width:45% !important;
      padding-left: 10px !important;
    }
    .searchicon {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fund-search" type="search" class="searchbox" placeholder="Search">
    <i class="material-icons right searchicon" ng-click="toggleSearch()">search</i>
```

Comment: I am unable to get the same bug you described above. Do you have more descriptive reproduction steps?

Comment: @AlexBieg hm, did you see in the fiddler? when I click the search icon and then click it again to close it. its leaving a light input line for me...

Comment: Hmm what browser are you using? It seems to work fine on chrome and safari.

Comment: @AlexBieg I'm using chrome on windows. This is not happening on IE